# How to connect SATA drives without USB

Tags: hard-drive

I want to connect a SSD SATA HDD to the pi without using USB.

Possible?

I was hoping some sort of module would be available or a way of connecting using a breadboard.

Tried searching on stack overflow and Google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Worth reviewing this answer on `ee.se`

> https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/118537/interfacing-with-sata-in-embedded-systems

In short, not simple. In the most reasonable scenario, besides USB of course, you would use a [JM20330](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/download_datasheet.php?id=2755473&part-number=JM20330) PATA<->SATA converter chip and you would bit-bang the PATA interface via GPIO with reduced bandwidth (16 bit PATA)

It's not possible to obtain the IC individually without contacting JMicron directly, but you may use an assembled converter card like [this one on newegg](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIACJF54C2865)

---

You may find a high end microcontroller or microprocessor will have integrated SATA controller peripheral. These are expensive specialty parts.

Most commercially available standalone  SATA controller IC's have either USB or PCIE host interfaces. They are also... not easily obtainable and certainly not bread-boardable  For example

- [Marvel 88SE1495](https://www.marvell.com/storage/system-solutions/sata-controllers/) -- Datasheet under NDA, 679 ball BGA component, PCIe Interface
- [Microsemi PM8001C](https://www.microsemi.com/product-directory/sas-sata-i-o-controllers/4046-6g-sas-sata-i-o-controllers-storage) 1000+pin BGA, PCIe, Datasheet under NDA
- [TI TUSB9261](http://www.ti.com/product/TUSB9261) 70Pin QFP, USB
- [Not that many, when doing a product search on mouser!](http://www.mouser.com/All-Manufacturers/Semiconductors/Interface-ICs/_/N-45lraZ0?Keyword=SATA)

You can persue an FPGA solution to bridge a SATA controller soft-core to your raspberry pi host using the interface of your choice. But this is not for the faint of heart and requires capital resources.

Comment: Bitbanging is truly the solution to all interfacing problems with the Pi ... i expect PCIe support soon. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You sir, need to improve your Googling skills! "Raspberry Pi SATA" returned loads of fruit. I personally use a PlusberryPi case but they are like hens teeth now - very rare. Maybe [this](https://www.scan.co.uk/products/lycom-pi-102-raspberry-pi-usb-to-msata-converter-board-supports-sata-i-ii-iii-msata-ssds-with-mounti)?

Comment: That uses USB. specifically said no USB.

Answer (score 0):

I also can't see anything released for data transfer by GPIO. [This looks unintrusive.](https://m.aliexpress.com/s/item/32791789269.html?trace=storeDetail2msiteDetail&spm=2114.12010608.0.0.3FVxrE#autostay)

Comment: That's also USB. If its not possible without using the USB interface, then that would be the valid answer.